# Arrays printing sum of values

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with counting the sum of values from each line in a multidimensional array in the language C.

Example:

My array with values:

```
   1  2  3  4     
   5  6  7  8                                         
   9 10 11 12
```

My result array should be:

```
       10
       26      
       42
```

`w` - count lines
`k` - count columns

```
int tab[w][k]; <-- this is a table just with values(it's example) 
int sum[] = {0};
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<w;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<k;j++)
     {
       sum[i] = sum[i] + tab[i][j];
     }
}
```

It doesn't work well. I've tried do it another way but it only counted the first row.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: What is the resulting output?

Comment: This line of code `int sum[] = {0};` - What do you think that the compiler can ascertain the size of the array? Perhaps one item!

Comment: i - count lines, j - count columns, w number of lines (3) and k number of columns (4). Better use another domain for counters and dimensions. (i,j,k,l) counters, (m,n,o,p) dimensions, for example.

Comment: It shows me like an address to memory of the table sum, but I don't use '&'

Comment: Hmmm and what is the **code** that displays `sum`?

Comment: @ikrabbe can you write it down below my post, please

Comment: if you want to have `w` sums, you need to declare that: `int sum[w];`

Comment: @ringø no, it doesn't show me sum, it look like an address to the memory of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sum[] = {0}* should be *sum[w];*, and you should fill it with zeroes before doing the sums.

Then just sum like you did, you can do it better using *+=*, that works the same as your original code but is easier to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define w 3
#define k 3


int tab[w][k] = {  
   {0, 1, 2},
   {3, 4, 5},
   {6, 7, 8}
};


int main()
{
    int sum[w];
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < w ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < k ; j++)
        {
            sum[i] += tab[i][j];
        }

        printf("sum[%d] = %d\n", i, sum[i]);
    }  
}
```

Then your code should run fine

Comment: ok, my fault, just use a for loop so.

Comment: It doesn't work, can you write it down below my post, my brain is mixed now :) , please

Comment: @George, just initialize your sum array as having w elements: *int sum[w];*, then initialize it with zeroes and then do the same two for loops sum, that you did well

Comment: @freinn another way to fill an array sum with zeros ? without using fill method ?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
   {
       suma[i] = 0;
   }  
 ?

Comment: @George just use the for loop I put on my answer, which is the same of your last comment.

Comment: Can you write here how will be look for loop to print sum array with values, maybe i do sth bad, please

Comment: @George done. it works fine on my computer.

Comment: OK, IT WORKS in my example, thanks!